Azure Function (Linux) ZipDeploy not working
For some time now, I've used ZipDeploy to publish .NET 8 Azure Function Apps to Windows hosts.  The process is:

Create the Windows Function App in Azure In Visual Studio
publish to local folder
ZIP the data
Use the ZipDeploy details obtained from the Fn's Deployment Center's Publish Profile.

So I do the exact same thing as above, but substitute Windows for Linux.
When I deploy this (I happen to use Postman to push) I get a 200 OK response.  Just like normal :-)
But when I go to the Overview pane in Azure, it first takes an age to load, and then the list of Functions is not displayed:

The details are around a time-out issue.  But, if I navigate to any of my Windows FN Apps then the Function details loads immediately, so it's Azure being slow.
I have the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE set to 1 (it's running on an App Service plan).
In the "Diagnose and solve problems > Deployment" and dig into Function App Status after deployment, I see:

The Function's trigger is from a Service Bus queue, and - needless to say - it all runs perfectly in Visual Studio.
Note: I also have tried doing the deploy direct to Azure from Visual Studio.  It all looks to be successful, but same effect.

#1 Can you deploy a hello world just to try? #2 Also check the content of the zip

@JRichardsz, First, I tried deploying my FN to a Windows Fn, still no luck.  I therefore did as you suggested, created a brand new HTTP trigger hello world FN (new project/soln) and published it to my Azure Fn - same issue.  Not seeing anything in the logs that jumps out to me.

Did RithwikBojja answer helped you?

Thanks @JRichardsz and @RithwikBojja - I finally figured it out.
There was red-herring in my HelloWorld Fn app; I updated the NuGet packages and then that worked.  So the problem was definitely with my actual application.
The problem turned out to be that my Environment variables had a . in the name.  For example MyService.BaseUrl and MyService.Timeout.  This naming convention worked fine on Windows but not on Linux.  I swapped out . for _ and now everything works.


First, I tried deploying my FN to a Windows Fn, still no luck.

In Windows Function App, Set the below app settings in your function app:
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT as true

Then deploy the zip. The function will be visible as below:


I am facing similar issue with Linux, AFAIK, it is a bug, I would suggest you to raise a support ticket for it.

I didn't find this necessary.  For .NET all the compilation is done prior to deployment.
